# Getting all event receiver in a site collection via C# or Powershell | SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, csom, event-receivers

I am trying to get all event receivers in a site collection for all lists and libraries.

Is there any way to do so?

I have got articles where they find it for content types but not for any lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerShell below for your reference:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://sp2013/sites/team"
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.Title
    $web.Lists | Where {$_.EventReceivers.Count -gt 0} |  Select Title,EventReceivers | Format-List
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The article [SharePoint 2010: Find Event Receivers Attached to Lists](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7070.sharepoint-2010-find-event-receivers-attached-to-lists.aspx) describes how this can be done for SP2010 with PowerShell, but it should equally work for 2013.

```
$GC = Start-SPAssignment            
$Site =  $GC | Get-SPSite http://yourserver/sites/yoursite            
$Web = $Site.Rootweb            
$Web.Lists |            
   Where {$_.EventReceivers.Count -gt 0} |            
   Select Title,EventReceivers |            
   Format-List            
Stop-SPAssignment $GC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but only for rootweb not for the whole site collection.